# in mongodb, I have a collection that has DBRef to another collection. How can I copy this collection with DBRef intact?

Tags: mongodb, import, reference, copy, export

in mongodb, I have a collection that has DBRef to another collection. How can I copy this collection and the referenced collection to another DB with DBRef intact? I tried using the export and import feature on Compass, but with this method, the references don't seem to be imported into the new DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the export and import feature on Compass to copy the information from one mongodb installation to another. The DBRef on the Collection at the new site were undefined for the Collection, but the id was intact. So I just had to manually go through and update all the documents in the collection to reference the correct Collection. This solved the problem.